# How to properly setup X forwarding on (Ubuntu) linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, x11, x11forwarding

From my desktop, I can get to my wife's machine on the lan using:  `ssh -X user@1.2.3.4`.  Both systems are running the desktop flavour of Ubuntu 9.10-64bit.

But here is the problem:  When I try to run X apps like `gedit`, it fails with the following error message on the remote end of the ssh connection: "`X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication`".

The strange thing is, if I run the app with "`sudo`" such as "`sudo gedit`" then everything works fine:  I get the X application forwarded through my ssh connection and showing up on my desktop, even though it is actually running on the remote machine.

What have I missed, or where do I check to see exactly what permission failure is giving me problems when running as non-sudo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncomment the below in /etc/ssh/ssh_config on both machines.

```
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted no
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  This remote box has a ssh_config file based on a Debian 5 example instead of the usual Ubuntu one.  Thanks.